# Postman : Assert for more than one Value to be present in response

Tags: api, postman

I am new to Postman, i have a scenario where 2 expected values are present in the response under "Name" key

The response is as below - i need code to check whtr "bs i acct type 1" and "bs i acct type 2" are present in the response under "name" tag. can anyone suggest how to check ?

```
{
    "StoredValueAccounts": [
        {
            "Id": 41,
            "AccountNumber": 41,
            "StoredValueAccountShareType": "Standard",
            "CurrencyCodeIsoAlphabetic": "USD",
            "Balance": 21568.07,
            "TypeName": "bs i acct type 1",
            "StoredValueAccountTypeId": 26,
            "StoredValueAccountAssociationType": "Individual",
            "Name": "bs i acct type 1",
            "BalanceForward": 0.0,
            "CreditLimit": 0.0
        },
        {
            "Id": 42,
            "AccountNumber": 42,
            "StoredValueAccountShareType": "Standard",
            "CurrencyCodeIsoAlphabetic": "USD",
            "Balance": 10000.0,
            "TypeName": "bs i acct type 2",
            "StoredValueAccountTypeId": 27,
            "StoredValueAccountAssociationType": "Individual",
            "Name": "bs i acct type 2",
            "BalanceForward": 0.0,
            "CreditLimit": 0.0
        },
        {
            "Id": 43,
            "AccountNumber": 43,
            "StoredValueAccountShareType": "Standard",
            "CurrencyCodeIsoAlphabetic": "USD",
            "Balance": 10000.0,
            "TypeName": "bs i acct type 3",
            "StoredValueAccountTypeId": 28,
            "StoredValueAccountAssociationType": "Individual",
            "Name": "bs i acct type 3",
            "BalanceForward": 0.0,
            "CreditLimit": 0.0
        },
],
    "Operation": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to collect all `Name` key values in array then use [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to assert this array includes expected values.

**Collect** `Name` **key values:**

```
let nameKeyValues = response["StoredValueAccounts"].map(storedValueAccount => storedValueAccount.Name);
```

**Check that this array includes expected values using includes and postman assertions**

```
pm.expect(nameKeyValues.includes("bs i acct type 1") || nameKeyValues.includes("bs i acct type 2")).to.eql(true);
```